# Jquery error in fetching json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
members = $.parseJSON(members);
$.each(members, function (i, item) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "'.base_url(" / panel / listNottifications ").'/'.$id.'/" + 
                 valueSelected,
        data: {
            list: item[i]
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data){
            var w = $("#Eventprogress").width() + perRequest + "%";
            $("#Eventprogress").attr("data-original-title", w);
            $("#Eventprogress").animate({
                width: w
            }, 600);
        }
    });
});
```

Members is an returned json var from get request equal as example

```
["11111|22222|3333|4444|555555"]
```

the error i got in fetching is ..

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token |
```

any ideas how to fetch the returned data ?

Thanks

Comment: How about sending valid JSON ?

Comment: how to make it in the right way , notice that i need all of those ids to be in one value array('11111|22222|3333|4444|555555'); as example .

Comment: Why would you split an array with a pipe, just drop the pipe and it should work fine.

Comment: foreach ($users as $key => $User) {
              $User = implode('|', $User);
              $Fifty[$key] = $User; 
        }
             echo json_encode($Fifty);

Comment: because i need to make every 50 values at least in one value in the array .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not a JSON response, the json response should be an object with key, value syntax or an array or such objects,
this is neither one of them, but anyway you can check if the JSON is valid in [Json Link](http://www.jsonlint.com/)

Comment: i get " Valid JSON " !

Comment: This is perfectly valid JSON representation of the array containing a string.

Comment: @dfsq so , how can i send it in an request , " it might have more that 1 value " ..

Comment: just put commas between the values